# How to stop the automatic run command?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

There was a virus(.exe) which was running randomly through cmd. I managed to delete the executive file which was infected. But the command still runs randomly and I keep getting the error that `Windows cannot find filename.exe`.

I am pretty sure that the virus is gone, but there is a script which is still there I think and I can not find it anywhere.

How do I stop it? Command prompt just pops up every 10-15 minutes with this error.

I am on Windows 10 32-bit OS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a dozen places where these random runs can originate from. If the core of your Windows operating system is compromised the only reliable way is to boot from Live CD and run your Antivirus from it.

If your Windows isn't compromised but you have just these random runs of .exe from undetermined sources, use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) utility from Sysinternals suite.  It will show you all places where automatic launches can start from: Startup folder, registry Keys, system DLL hooks etc. and you will be able to remove rogue .exe

Comment: Thank you so much maoizm. I will try the solutions you have provided and will revert back if it works

Comment: @Abhishek yes please. from my experience either your system is totally wasted or 95% chances that Autoruns will help you. If so, feel free to accept this as a valid answer ;)